# NullReferenceException with Autofac WebApi and OData v4

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, autofac

I have an OData v4 WebApi controller and Autofac WebApi Integration v3.4. I have a few Autofac filters registered (not sure if that matters) and getting this error when I attempt to access the OData controller. I have no problems accessing standard Api controllers.  I didn't see any information suggesting incompatibility with OData v4 and Autofac.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to work around this issue? While not preferable, do I need to roll back to a prior version of OData? Autofac is pretty well integrated, so I won't replace that with another IoC container.  I'd rather roll back OData if need be. Thanks!

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"An error has occurred.","innererror":{
      "message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","type":"System.NullReferenceException","stacktrace":"   at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiFilterProvider.GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__1`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.<RemoveDuplicates>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.InitializeFilterPipeline()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.GetFilterGrouping()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my OData controller:

```
public class RequestsController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly PtoDbContext _db;
        public RequestsController(PtoDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Request> Get()
        {
            return _db.PtoRequests;
        }

     }
```

Here's my OData route configuration:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<Request>("Requests");
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: "odata",
                model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Comment: I also ran through the option to add an OData v3 endpoint with Entity Framework and followed the instructions [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/creating-an-odata-endpoint#add-controller) and got the same null reference exception.

Comment: Did you get to resolve this issue? Am facing similar issue.

Comment: Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Per https://odata.github.io/WebApi/#13-04-DependencyInjection
for custom DI like AutoFac you need to use another OData route configuration overload (the one with configure action which configures the container builder) after you register your container builder with http configuration.